# Javamail's getUnreadMessagesCount() returns whole amount of mails instead of unread ones

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I connect to my email box vie POP3 and get unread messages count. There're 10 mails in the box with only 1 in unread state. But Folder.getUnreadMessagesCount() returns 10 instead of 1.
Is this a problem within mail provider settings or I do something wrong?

Here's what I do:

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new EMailAuthenticator(getLogin(), getPassword()));
Store store = session.getStore();
store.connect();

Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
inbox.getUnreadMessageCount();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

POP3 has no method to track read or unread messages (see [RFC1939](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt)), so JavaMail will treat all messages as unread. If you want to be able to track read and unread e-mails, then you need to use IMAP.

Comment: This is explained in more detail in the [JavaMail javadocs for the com.sun.mail.pop3 package](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html).